# No "asset library" drop down menu in file paths in blender preferences

Tags: customization, asset-browser

I want to add an asset path to blender but there's no possible option for this. It seems to be completely removed for some reason.

There's nothing I can try really, pls help :)

Comment: What Blender version are you using? Can you share a screenshot that shows that it is missing?